# index out of range even after initialization of var serving as index

Tags: python, indexing

I dont understand why this is out of range if I initialize j.

This expansion iterates all preceding characters of a slash, and when combined with a space, it is multiplied.

ie

```
    5</ --> 5<5<
    5<// --> 5<5<5<
    5</ / --> 5<5< 5<5<
```

Also, is this the best way to accomplish my task?

```
    def ttExpand( program ) :
        """
        expand the string manipulation symbols in program into
        a TinyTurtle language program.
        program -- a TinyTurtle string, possibly with string manipulation symbols
        Returns -- a TinyTurtle string after expansion
        """
        new_program = ''
        array = []
        i = 0
        j = 0
        for ch in program: #while program.index(ch) != len(program) - 1:

            if ch == '/':
                array.append(program.index(ch))
                i += 1
        if len(array) == 0:
            return program

        while j <= len(array):
            new_program += (program[:array[j]])
            j += 1
        return new_program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't produce the correct result, but it does do what you're *trying* to do:

```
#while j <= len(array):
for i in array:
    new_program += program[:i] #(program[:array[j]])
```

It would *appear* that this approach actually accomplishes what you want:

```
def tt_expand(program):
    '''
    expand string manip symbols

    Example:

    >>> tt_expand('5</')
    '5<5<'
    >>> tt_expand('5<//')
    '5<5<5<'
    >>> tt_expand('5</ /')
    '5<5< 5<5<'
    '''

    seen = ''
    new_program = ''
    prev_token = None
    for i, token in enumerate(program):
        if token == '/':
            if prev_token == ' ':
                new_program += new_program.rstrip()
            else:
                new_program += seen
        else:
            new_program += token
            seen += token
        prev_token = token

    return new_program



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: so what is if prev_token == ' ': doing, if prev_token is none?

Comment: `None != ''`, so it will skip that. If I understand correctly, the space is only relevant when it precedes a `/`. If the first character were a `/` then the prev would be None, not that it's terribly important,  since the program is empty at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause is using `while j <= len(array):` then indexing `array` with `j`; sequences have indices starting at `0` and ending `len(array) - 1` (usually described as being from 0 (inclusive) to `len(array)` (exclusive)).

The simple fix that preserves the majority of your code is to change to `while j < len(array)` so you stop at the last available index in `array`. That said, you're coding like you've just come from C, indexing instead of iterating.

If you ever find yourself with a loop that is structured like:

```
 i = 0
 while i < len(someseq):
     item = someseq[i]  # or equivalent, where you only use the value retrieved by indexing, not the index itself
```

what you really want is:

```
 for item in someseq:
```

In rare cases, you might also need the index (when assigning back to the original sequence) in which case you'd do:

```
 for i, item in enumerate(someseq):
```

Either of those is markedly faster and simpler than reinventing C-style `for` loops (rechecking the length on each pass and indexing adds a surprising amount of overhead compared to iterating directly).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do:

```
while j <= len(array) - 1
```

Comment: I had to change the j in: new_program += (program[:array[j]])  : to j-1

Thanks, do you have any recommendations for when the space modifies the slash?

Comment: The current problem is with: (program[:array[j-1]] * 2)
whicxh is multiplying a string by a number, which should be fine, but its not!

Comment: When you multiply string by integer you should expect that your string will become longer. For example: `'0'*3` will become `'000'`. Is this the case? If you get error, most probably you end up doing something like `'0'*'8' (string by string)`. If this is not helpfull please give more details what is a problem.